# How to get build time for an F# project?

Tags: build, f#

I tried putting in `--times` in the `Other Flags:` box inside the project Build tab in VS2015, but it is not working. I am not sure what to try next, but getting the build timing should be possible somehow.

For the context, I used the structural (duck) typing feature of F# too much in my project which tanked the build time, so I need to replace it with interfaces. Knowing the exactly how long it takes to build would be good.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/1530). There I'm isolation the code in scripts and measuring time there, it allows me to compare different pieces of code in one shot.

Comment: That is seriously great work, bravo. Just where are those scripts? Maybe you meant to link to something else as well?

Comment: Thanks. The [sample script](https://gist.github.com/gmpl/5c2fae2d6e6a115d729e) is linked in the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/343). Should be a better way to compare these times I would be also interested to know.

Comment: Actually, since it is possible to improve the constraint solver this much and the changes will be in the future version of F# and improving the build time is not a pressing issue and I hate casting interfaces...I think I'll actually keep the code as is. Unexpectedly, you have given me a more helpful reply than what an actual answer to this question would be for my particular situation. Thanks. The question of how to get build times not just from a script but from a compiled project is still up for grabs, though. It would be good to know.

Comment: I would think this is a function of msbuild, and not the compiler? Have you tried `Fake` it will output the build time. Otherwise you can run scripts from the Build Events tap of the project and increase the Build output verbosity in Tools|Options|General: Build and run.